# Edit dictionary in text file with python

Tags: python

I am working on a project where I am using Dictionary as a Database for storing the objects. However, I am not getting way got get into the Dictionary which is in Text file and unable to add more items inside.

My Text File:

a = {1:2,2:1}

My Code:
I am unable to find way to get way to append more items inside that dictionary.

Comment: Don't use a text file, use a .json file.

Comment: To do that you have to read in the text file, parse it (which results in a dictionary), add items to the dictionary, convert dictionary to text, write out the text. With which step do you have issues and what have you tried already?

Comment: Note that json files _are_ just text files in a [certain format](https://json.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Just an example, you can do many more things with python dictionary. Refer here for more: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

```
a = {
  "Index": 1,
  "Model": "2019",
  1: 2,
  2:1
}
import json
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:    # Writing to file here
     file.write(json.dumps(a))
file.close()

with open('file.txt') as file:         # Reading the file here
    data = json.load(file)
    print (data)
file.close()

data["type"] = "dictionary"            # Adding item to dictionary
print(data)
```

Output before adding item:

```
{'Index': 1, 'Model': '2019', '1': 2, '2': 1}
```

Output after adding item:

```
{'Index': 1, 'Model': '2019', '1': 2, '2': 1, 'type': 'dictionary'}
```